# How to fast prevent switching routing Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I listen routing:

```
this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(switchMap((parameters) => of(parameters)))
      .subscribe((params: Params) => {

       if (params.has("id")) {
         // Request to server
       }

       if (params.has("block")) {
         // Just add to array
       }

       if (params.has("request")) {
         // Request to server
       }
});
```

When I fast switching route to back and forth it sends a lot of requests to server in section `if (params.has("id")) {}` and `if (params.has("request")) {}`.

How to avoid it and why `.pipe(switchMap((parameters) => of(parameters)))` does not work?

Comment: Why the switchMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it needs to be more like this:

```
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap((parameters) => {
      if (params.has("id") {
        return this.serverRequest(params); // return the request, possibly add .pipe() if needed
      } else if (params.has("block")) {
        return of(params); // add to array here and return whatever
      } else if (params.has("request")) {
        return this.serverRequest(params); // return the request, possibly add .pipe() if needed
      }

      return of(params); // whatever default return here
    })
  ).subscribe((result) => {
    //handle your result

  });
```

`switchMap` doesn't cancel what happens in the final subscribe, it cancels what's happening in the inner observable, so the inner observable needs to be what you want to cancel. In general, nested subscribes are bad practice and mean you're doing something wrong.

you could also consider adding a `debounceTime` operator before your `switchMap` if you don't even want the requests to get sent if the route switching is happening very quickly.

Comment: What to do if I call component directly and it has `  ngOnInit(): void {}` with server request? I mean I dont have route params in some components

Comment: you can unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` or you could be using resolvers instead, but very quick route switching shouldn't be something your app is so concerned with. if your app is doing that often, you probably have deeper design issues.

Comment: So, what do you recommend when I have two components, they are activated by route, each has ngOnInit with request to server. If switch them fast it always sends requests

Comment: why are you so concerned with this use case? it's not a common one

Comment: Because client sends a lot of requests if click million times to one route and then to another, I need to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to router events and write your logic during the start of navigation

```js
import {
  Router,
  // import as RouterEvent to avoid confusion with the DOM Event
  Event as RouterEvent,
  NavigationStart,
  NavigationEnd,
  NavigationCancel,
  NavigationError
} from '@angular/router';

this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      // you can write your logic to stop what you want to stop
    }
});
```